# How to locate django logs in nginx docker setup?

Tags: django, nginx

I have my website build using below technology stack,

```
Django
GraphQL
Postgres
Nginx
Docker
```

Below is how my docker-compose file looked like,

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn sports_league.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/code/mediafiles
    environment:
      - PRODUCTION=true
    env_file:
      - ./config/.env.prod
    expose:
      - 8000
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/code/mediafiles
volumes:
  pgdata:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

When I run the django app locally, I can see the logs (print statements) on terminal.

However when I run it using Docker as a service, I don't see those in the container logs.

It looks like nginx is causing this to happen. I check nginx container logs as well, but I cannot find the logs there as well.

Below is how my nginx configuration file looks like,

```
upstream sports_league {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sports_league;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /code/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /code/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

Please help me to locate the logs or those print statements.

Answer (score 0):

I found the files at below location,

```
/var/log/nginx/
```

However those were not getting populated and after adding below line to nginx dockerfile, logs can be visible.

```
RUN rm -f /var/log/nginx/*
```